# How to register comm target in Jupyter lab?

Tags: kernel, jupyter-lab, comm

Following Jupyter notebook example on [Opening a comm from the kernel](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comms.html), I was able to initiate communication between the kernel and the notebook.

Every time I invoke `fetchData` -> It initiates a new connection, sends `fetchParams` and once it's ready it receives the data and activates a callback.

The code:

js

```
function fetchData(fetchParams, callback) {
    const comm =
    Jupyter.notebook.kernel.comm_manager.new_comm('comm_target', {{}})

    comm.send(fetchParams)

    comm.on_msg(function(msg) {
        const data = JSON.parse(msg.content.data['data']);
        if (callback) {
            callback(data)
        }
    });
}
```

python

```
get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager.register_target("comm_target", front_listener_get_data)
```

It's working fine on Jupyter notebook but when I'm running it on Jupyter lab - I get this error

`caught ReferenceError: Jupyter is not defined`

I found this [solution](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/blob/c629239ddb7219decd5a9df662c432ad6df5ef62/js/lab/src/plugin/comm.ts#L77), but it requires me to use `import { Kernel } from "@jupyterlab/services";` and nodejs, which I prefer not to do since it will break the current architecture of the entire project. This is a small feature within a bigger project.

any suggestions?